# Some doubts about C ++ operator overloading

Tags: c++

I could't understand this part in definition of class in C++,especially the operator and *this,I was a bit confused about these.(I am a beginner of C++）

```
SKNode& operator=(const SKNode*& node)
{
    key = node->key;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXLEVEL; i++)
    {
        forward[i] = node->forward[i];
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: "I am confused" isn't a specific question sorry. Please ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

This overloaded assigment operator assigns the specified node to the object itself.
When implementing for example:

```
A a1;
A a2;
A a3;
a1 = a2;
```

The last statement calls the operator of instance `a1`, copying in fact the contents of `a2` into `a1`.

The operator returns `*this`. In other words, a reference to itself.
In this way, you can use the construction:

```
a1 = a2 = a3;
```

This will first call the overloaded operator on instance `a2`, assigning `a3` to `a2` and then the overloaded operator of `a1`, assigning `a2` to `a1`.